# Insert into table two and update table two for BigQuery in one query

Tags: insert, google-bigquery, sql-update

I am using StandardSQL in BigQuery. I am writing a scheduled query which inserts records into table (2). Now, given that it's sceduled, I am trying to figure out how to update records in table (2) from the sceduled query, which is always inserting records into table (2).

In particular, when there is a record in table (2) but not generated by my query then I want to update table (2) and a boolean column to No.

Below is my query, where in the query would I add the update logic for table (2)?

```
INSERT INTO record (airport_name, icao_address, arrival, flight_number, origin_airport_icao, destination_airport_icao)


WITH
  planes_stopped_in_airport AS (
  SELECT
    p.IATA_airport_code,
    p.airport_name,
    p.airport_ISO_country_code,
    p.ICAO_airport_code,
    timestamp,
    a.icao_address,
    a.latitude,
    a.longitude,
    a.altitude_baro,
    a.speed,
    heading,
    callsign,
    source,
    a.collection_type,
    vertical_rate,
    squawk_code,
    icao_actype,
    flight_number,
    origin_airport_icao,
    destination_airport_icao,
    scheduled_departure_time_utc,
    scheduled_arrival_time_utc,
    estimated_arrival_time_utc,
    tail_number,
    ingestion_time
  FROM
    `updates` a
  JOIN
    Polygons p
  ON
    1 = 1
  WHERE
   a.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) and a.timestamp <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    AND ( latitude IS NULL
      AND longitude IS NULL
      AND callsign IS NULL
      AND speed IS NULL
      AND heading IS NULL
      AND altitude_baro IS NULL) IS FALSE
    AND ST_DWithin( ST_GeogFromText( polygon ),
      ST_GeogPoint(a.longitude,
        a.latitude),
      10)
    AND a.collection_type = '1' -- and speed < 50
    AND (origin_airport_icao IS NULL
    AND destination_airport_icao IS NULL) IS FALSE )
SELECT
  p.airport_name,
  icao_address,
  MIN(timestamp) AS Arrival,
  flight_number,
  origin_airport_icao,
  destination_airport_icao
FROM
  planes_stopped_in_airport p
WHERE 
  flight_number NOT IN (SELECT Distinct flight_number
                        FROM `table(2)`                                               
                        )
GROUP BY
  icao_address,
  p.airport_name,
  flight_number,
  origin_airport_icao,
  destination_airport_icao
HAVING
  flight_number IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  airport_name,
  arrival
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it with MERGE statement, see details in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement.

If I understood your requirements correctly, you need something like

```
MERGE dataset.Destination T
USING (SELECT * ...) S
ON T.key = S.key
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET T.foo = S.foo, T.bool_flag = FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ...
```